# How to print output of method in a struct with Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, function, methods

I'm VERY new to programming and Swift. Why won't a simple print(getDetails()) at the bottom of the getDetails function suffice to get the output? It always returns an error "Expected '{' in body of function declaration".

Here's the code...

```
struct Car {
    let make:String = "MINI"
    let model:String = "COOPER"
    let year:String = "2015"
    
    var details:String {
        return year + " " + make + " " + model
    }
    func getDetails() -> String {
        return details
    }
    print(getDetails())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top level of a `struct` or `class`, you're only allowed to define functions and properties. For example, your `let make:String = "MINI"` or `func getDetails() -> String { ... }` are valid top-level declarations.

You are not, however, allowed to put imperative code that doesn't define a function or property (like `print("")`) at the top level of a type like this.

If you were in a Swift playground, you can put imperative code at the top level of the file (not of the struct or class). So, this would be valid:

```
struct Car {
    let make:String = "MINI"
    let model:String = "COOPER"
    let year:String = "2015"
    
    var details:String {
        return year + " " + make + " " + model
    }
    func getDetails() -> String {
        return details
    }
}

let myCar = Car()
print(myCar.getDetails())
```

Since all `getDetails` does is return `details`, it's a bit superfluous, so we could refactor to just this:

```
struct Car {
    let make:String = "MINI"
    let model:String = "COOPER"
    let year:String = "2015"
    
    var details:String {
        return year + " " + make + " " + model
    }
}

let myCar = Car()
print(myCar.details)
```